# How do I make the returned values of a function so that they are not in a parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example I have a function

```
def function_1():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return x, y, z
```

which I want to call and store it a dictionary in another function

```
def function_2():
    dict = {}
    for i in range(10):
        dict[i] = function_1(), i
```

what I imagined the code to give me was a dictionary with keys like this:

```
{0: (1, 2, 3, 0), 1: (1, 2, 3, 1), 2: (1, 2, 3, 2)}.
```

But what I get instead is

```
{0: ((1, 2, 3), 0), 1: ((1, 2, 3), 1), 2: ((1, 2, 3), 2)}.
```

Now what I would like to get is the aforementioned format for every key. How can I go about and do that?

Comment: `function_1(), i` is a tuple with the result of `function_1` as the first element and `i` as the second. If you want to *append* to the tuple returned from `function_1`, do `function_1() + (i,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use tuple unpacking like below:

```
dict[i] = *function_1(), i
```

**Code**:

```
def function_2():
    dict = {}
    for i in range(10):
        dict[i] = *function_1(), i
```

Note: Please don't name your dictionary as [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: You, sir, are a king.

Comment: Please consider accepting answer by pressing tick on the left of answer. Thanks